# How to create plugins for a web application

Tags: python, django, plugins

I am developing web applications in python using Django framework. I would like to develop some plugins to extend the functionality of the app. Can anybody tell me how to start about it as i have found nothing specific for web apps in python.
And also can the plugins be developed in any language or should they be in python as well??

Plugin: Suppose I am writing a parser to parse different forms of data, then i want each plugin to take care of each type of data. They should be included only if required by the user. The user has to download the plugin and be able to work on it.

Thanks,
Harsha

Comment: define what is a plugin

Comment: I have edite my question. Check it out. glasslion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about how to create a package that other Python developers can import into their application, whether it be a Django project or not, and have it installable via easy_install or pip, you need to register for an account on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) and follow the [tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial) to get started.

If you want to write your "plugin" in a language other than Python, and offer that functionality on the web, regardless of language or platform, you need to create a [Web Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) to accept input and return output, usually in XML or JSON format.

Working with a Web Service is NOT like working with a Python package. There is nothing to download or install, there are simply URL endpoints that respond to HTTP verbs.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make scripts that parse data and then fill your database with it then check Django documentation on how to write custom django-admin commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-management-commands/
Such commands will use django env and will have access to your models.